# Different .env file for different URL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application running at `www.myapp.com` with its own logos and all, the logo file location is defined in a .env file.

Now I want to have a white-label of `www.myapp.com` application on `www.whitelabel.com` with its own logo.

I need to have two different .env files that need to be loaded at runtime e.g. 
- for `www.myapp.com` in URL it should use `.myapp.env` file
- and for `www.whitelabel.com` it should use `.whitelabel.env` file.

Is this possible in Laravel 5.1, if yes how?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it using `Dotenv::load` function in Laravel 5.1. Add following code in `bootstrap/app.php` before `return $app;`

```
$environmentPath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$environmentFile = null;
switch (getenv('HTTP_HOST')) {
    case 'whitelabel.com':
        $environmentFile = '.whitelabel.env';
        break;
}
if (!empty($environmentFile) && file_exists($environmentPath . $environmentFile)) {
    Dotenv::load($environmentPath , $environmentFile);
}
```

Hope it help someone.